# CURL: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have a problem with CURL.

When I run the code below, exception: "CURL: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" is thrown. 
The cacert.pem is from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

```
protected static function curlHttpPost($url, $data) {
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            $verifyFile = Yii::getAlias('@common') . '/curl/cacert.pem';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            if(file_exists($verifyFile))
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $verifyFile);
            }
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $curlError = curl_error($ch);       
            if($curlError)
            {
                throw new Exception($curlError);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $response;
        }
```

Comment: Add      `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`   Before `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

Comment: So basically it doesn't work with localhost? If I don't have an SSL certificate then I can't use this method?